# How to use geocoding with codeigniter? At the moment I'm using Biostall's Google Maps v3 API

Tags: codeigniter, geocoding

I want to save postal address to a database with its co-ordinates do you guys
have any idea of how to do it with codeigniter and geocoding?

```
public function save()
{
    $postal = "";
    $orgName= ($this->input->post('InputName'));
    $category= ($this->input->post('category'));
    $streetNo= ($this->input->post('StreetNo'));
    $streetName= ($this->input->post('StreetName'));
    $suburb= ($this->input->post('Suburb'));
    $state= ($this->input->post('state'));
    $postCode= ($this->input->post('PostCode'));
}
$postal = $streetNo.' '.$streetName.' '.$suburb.' '.$state.' '.$postCode.' Australia';
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$postal&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

$markers = array(
    'name' => $orgName,
    'address' => $postal,
    'lat' => $lat,
    'lng' => $long,
    'catagory' => $category
);

$postal = "";
$long = "";
$lat = "";
$geocode = "";
$output = "";

$markers_id = $this->Home_Model->addLatLong($markers);
```

Comment: And whats the difference between your question title and question

Comment: please provide more information!?!

Comment: @Uchiha  sorry mate I updated the question... if could answer it that would appreciated.

Comment: [Check This](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+get+postal+address+from+lat+long+using+google+map+api+in+ci&oq=how+to+get+postal+address+from+lat+long+using+google+map+api+in+ci&aqs=chrome..69i57.38228j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+get+lat+long+using+google+map+api+in+ci)

Comment: Glad to help @MariusFlevie. Do I need to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Uchiha yes please.!!! But there seems to an error, every time I save a record same Lat and long coordinate saving to the table I don't know why

Comment: @Uchiha I'll update the question

Comment: I just tried commenting on your (now deleted) question. Can you expand on the comment you've added to your code, "it is not working"? That's not a very informative failure report. Have you examined `$geocode` to see if it has anything inside it?